# SortedSet<T> Remove function not removing

Tags: c#-4.0

I've created a `SortedSet<ALine>` object, however, when calling `S.Remove(S.First())` the first element of the set is not removed. I've encountered this problem before and back then it related to the `ALine.CompareTo` method not being implemented correctly (the function never returned `0` because two lines with the same length shouldn't be treated as equal), however after fixing it the problem still occurs with some of my tests (not all!).

The `ALine` class can be found at the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Algoritme.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a line between two points.
    /// </summary>
    public class ALine : IComparable<ALine>
    {
        public APoint Point1 { get; set; }
        public APoint Point2 { get; set; }
        public int NumTerminals { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor using two points
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p1">The starting point</param>
        /// <param name="p2">The ending point</param>
        public ALine(APoint p1, APoint p2)
        {
            if (!p1.Equals(p2))
            {
                this.Point1 = p1;
                this.Point2 = p2;

                if (p1.GetType() == typeof(ATerminalPoint))
                {
                    NumTerminals = NumTerminals + 1;
                }
                if (p2.GetType() == typeof(ATerminalPoint))
                {
                    NumTerminals = NumTerminals + 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Start and end points may not be the same");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor using four icoordinates
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x1">The x coordinate of the starting point</param>
        /// <param name="y1">The y coordinate of the starting point</param>
        /// <param name="x2">The x coordinate of the ending point</param>
        /// <param name="y2">The y coordinate of the ending point</param>
        public ALine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            this.Point1 = new APoint(x1, y1);
            this.Point2 = new APoint(x2, y2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the length of a line, which is measured by the Euclidean distance between the start and end points of the line.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Double containing the length of the line </returns>
        public double Length()
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((Point2.X - Point1.X), 2) + Math.Pow((Point2.Y - Point1.Y), 2));
        }

        // override object.Equals
        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Equals(obj as ALine);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if the line equals another given line. Lines are considered equal when their start and end points are equal, or their inverse is.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other">The line to check with</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Equals(ALine other)
        {
            if ((this.Point1.Equals(other.Point1) && this.Point2.Equals(other.Point2)) || (this.Point2.Equals(other.Point1) && this.Point1.Equals(other.Point2)))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        // override object.GetHashCode
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Point1.GetHashCode() ^ Point2.GetHashCode();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Lines are compared first by their length. If the length is equal, lines that connect TerminalPoints are preferred.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int CompareTo(ALine other)
        {
            if (this.Equals(other))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (this.Length() > other.Length())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.Length() < other.Length())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            // Count the number of TerminalPoints for each line.
            else if (this.NumTerminals > other.NumTerminals)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full ALine class code please ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? I guess you must have a problem in your Equals/GetHashCode implementation either in ALine or APoint. If the problem does not happen everytime, you could set up a conditional breakpoint to stop execution only when it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging it turned out that the comparison between `S.First()` and its successors returned `1`, which - for some reason - meant that `S` thought its order was broken and therefore refused to remove the element.

Changing `this.NumTerminals > other.NumTerminals` to `this.NumTerminals >= other.NumTerminals` seems to have fixed the problem.

It is strange, however, that no specific feedback is presented to the user when such a thing happens. Anyway, thanks Marshall for the help!